# Why is Shadow Catcher not working

Tags: rendering

[image]I’ve seen other questions about the settings for Shadow Catcher, however everything I’ve seen I have tried.
Using Cycles / GPU.
Set Film to Transparent.
Set to PNG / RGBA.
Set only the plane to Shadow Catcher.
The spotlight is set to cast shadows.
There is no material property in the plane.
The plane is set to receiving shadow caustics (not sure if that helps).
Screengrabs of settings attached including render setup, objects and export setup.

Comment: The shadow catcher is a Blender-specific tool; other tools may and probably will not support it.  You can bake the shadow of your plane to an image texture, which is readily understood by most 3D programs.